# Unable to load an .xlsx file from my computer to Google Colab

Tags: pandas, dataframe, upload, google-colaboratory, xlsx

I tried a few methods that I read online, but none seem to work. I have the file locally on my machine in a xlsx form and tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Then I uploaded the file succesfully and when I tried to read it into a df, I got the following error:

```
df = pd.read_excel(io.StringIO(uploaded['File_Name.xlsx']))
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 df = pd.read_excel(io.StringIO(uploaded['File_Name.xlsx']))
>
> TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uploading the file you can use it like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(uploaded['File_Name.xlsx'])
```

Pandas [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) can directly use bytes, there's no need to wrap it in `io.BytesIO(uploaded['File_Name.xlsx'])` (which would also work, but as xlsx is a binary file `read_excel` needs `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`).

Answer (score -1):

Run this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import re
import io 

#IMPORTING
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

ARCHIVE = pd.read_excel('archive.xlsx')
```